# How to make slider longer in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, frontend

I made the slider but want it to be longer.
I've tried changing the mainAxisAlignment also but no result. Please help me with this I want a slider with at least half the width of container

```
 Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('AGE',style: xcontainer_text_style,),
            Row(
              children: [
                SizedBox(width: 20.0,),
                Expanded(
                  child: SliderTheme(
                    data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                        thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 10.0),
                        thumbColor: Colors.redAccent[400],
                        overlayColor: Color(0x29ff0116),
                        overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 20.0),
                        activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
                        inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey[500],
                        trackHeight: 3.0,
                    ),
                    child: Slider(
                      value: age.toDouble(),
                      min: 1.0,
                      max: 100.0,
                      onChanged: (double newValue){
                        setState(() {
                          age = newValue.round();
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10.0,),

                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline ,
                      textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                      children: [
                        Text(age.toString(),style: xhieght_container_text_style ),
                        Text('', style: xhieght_container_unit_text_style,)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
```

and this is how it looks--

[this is how my app is currently looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLqvj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

*Add a `Flex` Value to your `Expanded` Widget Of `SliderTheme`*

```
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,  //increase or decrease this value to change the length of the slider
            child: SliderTheme(
              data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
```

More About `Flex` widget [Read HERE](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible/flex.html)

And More about `Expanded` Widget [Read HERE](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-expanded-widget-examples)